# apt-file list shows only two files for nginx package

Tags: apt, apt-file

I wanted to check how many files come with the `nginx` package. However the corresponding command seems to indicate that the package comes with only two files (?)

```
$ apt-file list nginx
nginx: /usr/share/doc/nginx/changelog.Debian.gz
nginx: /usr/share/doc/nginx/copyright
```

How is this possible given that e.g. the corresponding list for `apache2` contains 197 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Debian documentation](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nginx), `nginx` is a *dependency package*:

> This is a dependency package to install either nginx-full (by default), nginx-light or nginx-extras.

And, quoting [Debian Wiki's Glossary](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary#dependency-package):

> **Dependency package**
>   An empty *binary package* that exists only for the sake of its declared dependencies on other packages, for instance to keep the current default version of `gcc` installed. See *metapackage* and *transitional package* for other common types.

The corresponding [package page for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nginx) is slightly less clear in that it doesn't include the "dependency package" note. Still, Ubuntu adopts a similar packaging strategy.